# How can we solve this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can we solve this differential equation? 
$$ z' = e^z $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separation of variables:

$\frac{dz}{dt}=e^z$ leads to $e^{-z}dz=dt$. Hence

$$\int e^{-z}dz=t+C.$$

Your turn !

Comment: $$ z(t) = - ln(-(t+C))$$

Comment: Why the downvote ??